# Can cifs-utils be used to access a Debian/Linux filesystem from Windows?

Tags: linux, windows-7, debian, mount, samba

I need to access files on a Debian 10 machine from a Windows 7 PC. The Debian machine is just a VirtualBox VM on the same Windows PC host. The Debian machine has a minimal Command Line Interface environment.

I tried installing `samba`, which would work for what I need but, with all its dependencies, the 200 Megs footprint seems excessive, especially compared to `cifs-utils` which has a tiny install size.

All the articles I have come across mention using `cifs-utils` to access a Windows share from within a Linux machine but I can't find documentation for the other way round.

Can I configure `cifs-utils` to access the Debian machine from Windows and, if so, how?

Comment: Have you tried installing the virtualbox guest additions?  Even though you don't need the graphics stuff.. it also comes with a driver [to allow sharing](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#sharedfolders) between host and client.  Also.. network sharing the windows side to be used by the linux side is much easier than the inverse (due to file permissions).  Just write your files to the "windows side share".  If you don't need 100% speed.. who cares which side they are actually stored on?

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I can't do the inverse as you suggested, all the GUI tools such as Sublime etc. are on the host machine.I considered VirtualBox GA, but this Debian environment is bare bones and I did not want to burden it too much with unnecessary modules, hence the specific question about cifs-utils. In the end, if I can't do it with cifs-utils then so be it, I'd just like to be sure I can't.

Comment: What about a Linux Live CD/DVD to boot up the Linux machine. You can access it from that. I would not let it save to disk on exit though. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. `cifs-utils` is only intended to expose the Linux kernel API for acting as a Samba client, not the other way around.

Source: https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/LinuxCIFS

Comment: would sshfs work instead?

Comment: Yes, but I would try using the Guest Additions first